# Calculus, percentage of an interval for which a function is increasing

Tags: calculus, derivatives, percentages

So I have a question that asks,

> Given $f(x) = 7 + 10x ^ 3 - 5x ^ 4 - 2x ^ 5$ calculate the percentage of the interval $[-6, 4]$ on which $f(x)$ is increasing.

So from this I determined that I must differentiate $f(x)$ and determine the intervals for which $f(x)$ is increasing and decreasing. Then determine how many numbers of the interval $[-6, 4]$ $f(x)$ is increasing for and express this number as a ratio to how many numbers are in the interval and then convert this to a percentage.

So the derivative of

$$f(x) = -10x ^ 2(x + 3)(x - 1)$$

The inequality statements for which f(x) is increasing and decreasing are

$$x < - 3, f'(x) < 0$$
$$3 < x < 0, f'(x) > 0$$
$$0 < x < 1, f'(x) > 0$$
$$x > 1, f'(x) < 0$$

so from this I know that there are $2$ numbers for which $f(x)$ is increasing for and there are $11$ numbers in the interval because I'm including the $-6$ and $4$ so

$$\frac{2}{11} = \frac{x}{100} = 18.1818\%$$

So given

$$f(x) = 7 + 10x ^ 3 - 5x ^ 4 - 2x ^ 5$$

$f(x)$ is increasing for $18.1818\%$ of the interval $[-6 , 4]$.

Basically what I want to know is if my understanding of this question and my solution is correct? I have no idea how to check my work on the percentage part.

Comment: Assuming your differentiation is correct. $f'(x) >0 $ when $x$ is in $(-3,0)$ or $(1,4].$  That is $60\%$ of the interval.

Comment: You should get $40\%$of your interval. Note that we are not working with numbers here, we are working with intervals. The measure of an interval is the difference between it's end points. Hence, the answer should be $\frac{1-(-3) }{4-(-6)} = \frac{2}{5} = 40 \%$, on which the derivative is larger than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivative is positive on the intervals $(-3,0)$ and $(0,1)$. This constitutes a total length of $4$ out of the entire length of $10$. Therefore the answer is $40\%$.

Here is a little tool to help answer questions like these (over a single interval):

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2kxnwwcjh1

The percentage will be $$\dfrac{\text{Area of green rectangle}}{\text{Area of entire rectangle}}$$